# Spring AMQP sync to asynchronous by time

Tags: spring-amqp

### RabbitMQ Spring AMQP sync to async conversion

I need to convert synchronous message invocation into asynchronous if the request is running too long. If there a way to achieve this by using Spring AMQP client for RabbitMQ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can hand off to another thread at any time in your code and the container thread will immediately ack the message. But the logic to do the hand off has to be in your listener.

If you want to control the ack, use mode `MANUAL` and you'll need a `SessionAwareMessageListener` so you have access to the `Channel` to do the `basicAck`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. should I just set TTL for the sync queue and let the long running tasks to complete itself? If answer is yes, how could the consumer know the producer doesn't care anymore.